# Customised UIView compliation error message

Tags: objective-c, ios

Here is a code fragment

```
#import "MyCustomView.h"


@implementation MyCustomView

-(void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSLog(@"Help");
    CGContextRef myContext = [[NSGraphicsContext // 1

                               currentContext]graphicsPort];
```

....

Then at 1, I encountered this error message:

```
NSGraphicsContext undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Do you have any idea what caused it? Any header file I should include?

Comment: `NSGraphicsContext` sounds like a Mac class rather than from Cocoa Touch (though I've not done much graphics programming so I don't know for sure).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On iOS you have to use `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` to get the current CGContext. Your call is valid on Mac OS.

Answer (score 1):

`#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` (usually done in the .h file) should do it as long as you haven't removed the UIKit Framework from your project.